# Using dplyr functions in a pipe after ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

Is it possible to do a `summarise` after using ggplot in a pipe? The variable is not of great importance and I am just looking at the change for an exploratory purpose. Therefore, I don't really want to save the variable.

```
df %>% 
        mutate(change = t2 - t1) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = change)) +
        geom_histogram() %>%
        summarise(mean_change = mean(change))

Error in UseMethod("summarise_") : no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to 
an object of class "c('LayerInstance', 'Layer', 'ggproto')"
```

Is it possible to render ggplot output AND do a `summarise` (showing the mean) in the same pipe?

Comment: If you look at the `str` after the geom_histogram, it will be a ggplot object and not the original object from `df`

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I realised that. However, is it possible to render ggplot output AND do a `summarise` in the same pipe?

Comment: @Roland the function `hist` threw me an error: `'x' must be numeric` so I gave up on `hist`... But ggplot works fine

Comment: @Roland I edited my question by adding "Is it possible to render ggplot output AND do a summarise (showing the mean) in the same pipe?" Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but your question reminds me of the T-pipe in magittr (part of dplyr and the tidyverse), which I found in an online "R For Data Science" book here: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html#other-tools-from-magrittr .

With this T-pipe, you can ggplot and continue to summarise, as the T-pipe returns not the ggplot object but the object which was passed to ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

Using [package ggfun](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/ggfun) this would work :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/ggfun")
library(tidyverse)
library(ggfun)
iris %>% 
  mutate(x = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) +
  geom_density() -
  as_mapper(~{print(summarise(.,mean_x = mean(x)));.})
```

The `-` operator is used to apply a function on the data and still return a ggplot object, so we apply it to print but still return the original data to get our plot.